# Reverse Engineering Salted SHA1 Password Logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cryptography, passwords, password-encryption

I recently took over as an application administrator for an in-house developed app, an app which came with no documentation and no support.

I found out my predecessor gave the exact same initial password to every new user, and there is no password policy in place requiring users to change their password from the initial one defined. I know what the initial password is, and I would like to develop a SQL report to find out who has that password, so that I can force a password change.

*I am unable to write the SQL Code to mimic the behavior of the applications SHA1 hashing of the password and salt, and would like some help.*

I have set up the below example of what I've tried so far that anyone can copy/paste and toy with.

*Test Password: **Password1234!**

Salt (stored in SQL DB): **PvEdk1itxYINUl1m6tMSBQ==**

Password (stored in SQL DB): **K9VK3nis2lKMjGvgkuTogK/3Nac=***


Below you will find the SQL that I am using to do a proof of concept.

```
    DECLARE @Password varchar(100) = 'Password1234!'
    DECLARE @PasswordHex varbinary(max) = CONVERT(varbinary(max), @Password)
    DECLARE @Salt varchar(100) = 'PvEdk1itxYINUl1m6tMSBQ=='
    DECLARE @SaltHex varbinary(max)
    DECLARE @PasswordSaltHex varbinary(max)
    DECLARE @HashedPassHex varbinary(max)
    DECLARE @HashedPass varchar(max)
    --
    SET @SaltHex = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Salt"))', 'varbinary(max)')
    SET @PasswordSaltHex = @PasswordHex + @SaltHex
    SET @HashedPassHex = HASHBYTES('SHA1',@PasswordSaltHex)
    SET @HashedPass = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@HashedPassHex"))', 'varchar(max)')
    --
    PRINT @Password -- OUTPUT: Password1234!
    PRINT @PasswordHex -- OUTPUT: 0x50617373776F72643132333421
    PRINT @Salt -- OUTPUT: PvEdk1itxYINUl1m6tMSBQ==
    PRINT @SaltHex -- OUTPUT: 0x3EF11D9358ADC5820D525D66EAD31205
    PRINT @PasswordSaltHex -- OUTPUT: 0x50617373776F726431323334213EF11D9358ADC5820D525D66EAD31205
    PRINT @HashedPassHex -- OUTPUT: 0x727B312D682FA8766E6A498B0AF923FFDAF3778F
    PRINT @HashedPass -- OUTPUT: cnsxLWgvqHZuakmLCvkj/9rzd48=
```

*I would expect that the output of **@HashedPass** be the same as the Password stored in the database shown above, but they do not match.*

This is using SQL Server 2017, and I have relative certainty that hashing algorithm being used is SHA1.

Does anyone have recommendations on what I can do or try to resolve my issue?

Comment: For reference, I've already been working with the folks over at the Cryptography Stack Exchange site, and they referred me over here.
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68684/reverse-engineering-salted-sha1-password-logic-in-sql

Comment: How can we help? Surely you've just proved that the algorithm used *isn't* SHA1? Otherwise you would have a match?

Comment: Although you are doing a lot more than just SHA1 in the code above. I think you'll find the easiest approach would be to design a new method and force everything to change their password.

Comment: I don't have the autonomy to change anything. I don't have access to change the application code, and wouldn't know what to do with it if I did. What I have seen, IT LOOKS LIKE when a user logs in, the application is converting the password to hex, appending the salt (stored in hex in the DB) to the end of the password, and hashing it. Assuming thats what the application is doing, would my SQL code above be doing the same thing?

Comment: But you've added in the step of converting it to base64? But anyway without seeing any of the actual code, how can anyone else make useful suggestions? You just got to keep playing around until you get a match...

Comment: Is there not a standardized way of hashing passwords? I can likely get my hands on some VBA code that is also doing this same thing, but it might take me a few days to get the password to unlock that code. I can start that process, but it would be helpful if someone knew of a standardized process that differs from what I'm doing.

Comment: There are as many ways to hash a password as there are developers.